# Unable to successfully compile with boost using Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I am running OS X 10.11 (El Captain) and am trying to compile a program using C++ and boost. Specifically, I am trying using `boost::program_options` classes. The following code will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Options");
    return 0;
}
```

and returns the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
      processArgs(int, char const**) in test.o
  "boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
      processArgs(int, char const**) in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have boost 1.58.0 installed using brew, Xcode 7.0.1. I am using the Default Compiler (Apple LLVM 7.0) under Build Options, and have specified `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include` in Header Search Paths and `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib` in Library Search Paths. Additionally, I have checked the directories to ensure the proper files exist.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's compiling, but it's not linking. I believe you need to add `libboost_program_options.dylib` to your application under Link Binary With Libraries. See [this page](https://buddypanda.com/?p=10) for details (step 4).

The way I added the library was to select my target, then Link Binary With Libraries, then chose Add Other. The hardest part for me was navigating to /usr/local folder (I'm a novice at Xcode development). The way I did this was to go to the Finder and then select Go -> Go to Folder... then go to the folder /usr/local and then drag it from the bottom of the window to Favorites. It then shows up when you click Add Other in Xcode and you can easily navigate to the /usr/local/lib directory and find the boost libraries.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. Out of curiosity though, what does step 5 do? Does it copy any of the selectable files into the specified path - what is the point of this with a library?

Comment: I have to admit I didn't read the entire post I linked to - I was just looking for an example that showed adding the library.